# Extracting RGB values from symbology of .lyr or polygon file using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, symbology, arcgis-10.5, colormap

I have a polygon shapefile of geological units. Someone has already created a symbology and assigned standard colours to the units, available as a .lyr file.

What I need to do is create a list of the the 40+ units with their assigned RGB values using an ArcMap tool or maybe ArcPy.

I have been able to use polygon to raster, but it doesn't preserve the correct RGB values. That could be a feasible option and allow me to sample the colour if anyone has a suggestion on that path.

I have ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 Advanced License.

Comment: Does your polygon file already have RGB values stored in a field or fields?

Comment: Is this a single layer file, classified by an attribute?  And you want to get the RGB associated which each classification by attribute?  What is your desired output format?  A line of text + RGB value, ie- "MySoil- 120,35, 210" or something else?

Comment: Nope, not in the attribute table at least. Just a very specific colour ramp.

Comment: RyanDalton Yes its a single shapefile, there's also the lyr file associated with it. The colours are classified by attribute (unit name). Yes to getting the RGB value associated with each classification. A text file would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Export colored polygons as png raster with world file.
- Export result as grid format
- add components of above as separate grids
- Sample points inside polygons

[image]

Comment: Thanks FelixIP, but it still does not export with the correct colours, which is the same problem I had when making a geotiff with the polygon to raster tool. The result is closer but still not correct. 
Do you know why this would be?

Comment: Something to do with display color scheme. Perhaps play with outputs

Comment: Thanks for that, exporting the map as a .bmp + worldfile seemed to work, but only with the DPI way down (less than 75). The higher the DPI, the greater the divergence from the original colours for some reason. Also I double checked that the colour mode was set to 24-bit true colour.