# Exporting RGB values using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-10.6, rgb

I am working in ArcGIS 10.6 Desktop. I have several polygon shapefiles where the symbology is set to unique values. The amount of distinct values per shapefile is between 10 and 40. I assigned special colors to each value as RGB.

Is it possible to export those RGB values plus according field values into a text document at once instead of clicking on each symbology box and manually writing down the numbers?

Comment: Something close to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247723/extracting-rgb-values-from-symbology-of-lyr-or-polygon-file-using-arcgis-deskto

Comment: That is what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to export the RGB to text.

But if it's for reusing the same symbology in arcmap a good way to do it is to use style.
You may export your already set symbology to style them by laoding this new style in the symbol selector you will have access to the same symbology and your personal color will appear in the color selector. Also in the symbology tab of the layer properties you could choose the "Match to symbols" to apply the whole symbology in one click.

Related question : [Batch save symbols for each category of a layer as style in ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245486/batch-save-symbols-for-each-category-of-a-layer-as-style-in-arcgis/313929#313929)

More on Style : [A quick tour of symbols and styles](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/map/styles-and-symbols/a-quick-tour-of-symbols-and-styles.htm)

EDIT :

If you want the RGB value for using in another software you may export to style then open the style file in Access (just change the .style extention to .mdb) the color will be in the Colors table and the name should be the RGB value (if you want to keep the category you will need to manually fill the category tag in the style manager...), you can then export to Excel or to a text file from Access

[image]

Comment: I need the RGB info for postprocessing in Illustrator, but thank you.

Comment: @Anna I add a workaround to my answer, it's not perfect but at last you get a list of all the RGB value....

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was:

1. I used the Feature to Point-tool on my polygons and centered the points 'inside'.
2. I exported the polygon shapefiles to bitmap with worldfile attached (300dpi/24-bit true colour) to get the RGB values as raster values.
3. I loaded the bitmap and the point file and used the Extract Multi Values to Points-tool to get the values in the point attribute table.